# Bloc doesn't emmit state

Tags: dart, bloc

I am trying to use bloc in a command line application, but the bloc doesn't emmit new states.

I was expecting to go to the function 'porHacer', the initial state is EstadoInicial, which takes me to the function estadoInicial, there I add the event JugadorAgregado which emmits  a new state, Lobby, but that new state is never reflected  and  I never go to porHacer.
This a very simplified code, but it gives the intention

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:dart_console/dart_console.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';

sealed class Estado {}

class EstadoInicial extends Estado {}

class Lobby extends Estado {}

sealed class Evento {}

class JugadorAgregado extends Evento {}

class JuegoBloc extends Bloc<Evento, Estado> {
  JuegoBloc() : super(EstadoInicial()) {
    on<JugadorAgregado>(_onJugadorAgregado);
  }

  FutureOr<void> _onJugadorAgregado(event, emit) {
    emit(Lobby());
  }
}

final consola = Console();
final bloc = JuegoBloc();

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  do {
    var estado = bloc.state;
    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    var noImporta = switch (estado) {
      (EstadoInicial _) => estadoInicial(),
      _ => porHacer(),
    };
  } while (true);
}

void estadoInicial() {
  print('entré al estado inicial');
  bloc.add(JugadorAgregado());
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
}

void porHacer() {
  print('Aún no implementado');
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding of how `bloc` works and the logic of your code regarding it is absolutely correct.

However, there may be some misunderstanding about futures.

When you do

```dart
Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
```

you're discarding this future, so it's in practice equivalent to doing nothing.

To effectively wait for 2 seconds, you need to `await` it:

```dart
await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
```

That said, change your `estadoInicial` function to

```dart
Future<void> estadoInicial() async {
  print('entré al estado inicial');
  bloc.add(JugadorAgregado());
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
}
```

Since `estadoInicial` now returns a `Future`, change your `main` function to

```dart
//             Add `async` here:  vvvvv
void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  do {
    var estado = bloc.state;

    // Use a switch-statement here instead of a 
    // switch-expression, since only `estadoInicial`
    // is a function that returns a Future
    switch (estado) {
      case (EstadoInicial _):
        {
          // Await it
          await estadoInicial();
        }
      default:
        {
          porHacer();
        }
    }
  } while (true);
}
```

Now the code correctly outputs "Aún no implementado".